# Comparing String in Google App Script then Return to Userform

Tags: javascript, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I trying to build list of my local employee.

Currently using Excel VBA and it is working fine but my superior wants this to be online access.
So now I am using Google Sheets and Google App Script.
I am facing problem to do the search function. My code in VBA as follow-

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim whs As Worksheet
Dim NoKadPengenalan As String
Dim lastrowIC As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set whs = wb.Sheets("Data")

NoKadPengenalan = Trim(txtCarianIC.Text)
lastrowIC = whs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrowIC
If whs.Cells(i, 2).Value = txtCarianIC.Text Then
txtNama.Text = whs.Cells(i, 1).Value
txtIC.Text = whs.Cells(i, 2).Value
txtAlamat.Text = whs.Cells(i, 4).Value
txtTel.Text = whs.Cells(i, 5).Value
cmbPL.Value = whs.Cells(i, 6).Value
cmbZon.Value = whs.Cells(i, 7).Value
cmbStatus.Value = whs.Cells(i, 8).Value

Next

End Sub
```

How do I change those code in Google App script and return values to userform in the Google sheets.

I have try below codes but it returns nothing

```
var searchID= 0;

function Search()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("User Form"); //User Entry Form
  

  var str = formS.getRange("C3").getValue();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName(dataS).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++)
  {
    var rows = values[i];
    if (rows[searchID] == str)
    {
      formS.getRange("C6").setValue(rows[0]);
      formS.getRange("C8").setValue(rows[1]);
      formS.getRange("C10").setValue(rows[2]);
      formS.getRange("C12").setValue(rows[3]);
      formS.getRange("C17").setValue(rows[4]);
      formS.getRange("F6").setValue(rows[5]);
      formS.getRange("F8").setValue(rows[6]);
      formS.getRange("F10").setValue(rows[7]);
      formS.getRange("F12").setValue(rows[8]);
      formS.getRange("F14").setValue(rows[9]);
      formS.getRange("F16").setValue(rows[10]);
      formS.getRange("F19").setValue(rows[11]);
      formS.getRange("G19").setValue(rows[12]);
      formS.getRange("H19").setValue(rows[13]);
    }
  }
}
```

[This is my userform in google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saprd.png)
[This is my sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68xs1.png)

Comment: Please, share a spreadsheet instead of images. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: By the way, you can make easily 'markdown' tables (and paste them in your question) from your google spreadsheet tables with the addon **GenerateMarkdownTable** https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/generatemarkdowntable/23306117760

Comment: dataS is undefined

Comment: And probably it makes sense to use `break` statement in the loop. To avoid to iterate the rest of the rows once the condition was fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess. The `rows[searchID]` is `rows[0]`. As far as I can tell first column contains names. So it's a someone's name.

`str` is some ID (from cell "C3").

So here `if (rows[searchID] == str)` you're trying to compare the name from first column with ID from cell "C3". It doesn't make sense. You will get false always unless someone has a name like '96081001649'.